# I want to access the inner value of the StdClass object

Tags: php, laravel, stdclass

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [Table] => tbladmin [Create Table] => CREATE TABLE `tbladmin` ( `aid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `clgcode` varchar(7) NOT NULL, `name` text NOT NULL, `email` text NOT NULL, `mobile` text NOT NULL, `pass` text NOT NULL, `last_noti` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, `profilepic` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`aid`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ) )
```

How can I access the value of the created table in laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $array[0]->{'Create Table'};
```